# Optimizing Record Writing for Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Has anyone solved this problem in an efficient way?

Let's say you are writing to HDFS a massive .csv file with millions of records.  Normally some of the records will be split across physical HDFS blocks.  When MapReduce jobs are running a remote fetch will happen when there is a split record.

What would be great would be to be able to write the data in a more intelligent way that would allow for stopping short of using the entire block.  At write time you could easily determine how many records to put onto one block to make sure that no record is split.  By doing that a MapReduce job would never have to reach for a remote block.

Has anyone seen a way to do this?

Comment: Well, you probably shoudn't be writing CSV to begin with (even 1M records is fairly small in filesize), you would rather opt for Parquet or ORC, as they **are** optimized over columns (although still splittable). And I'd say Spark is more common than MapReduce nowadays... Sounds like what you are suggesting is pad your data with garbage to always round-up to match the block size?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to pad the block.   But I was hoping someone had a better idea.

Comment: Well, as mentioned - the better idea is to use different file formats and just not have small files. Alternatively, you can use blob storage rather than HDFS. You can follow the Hadoop Ozone project for more information on this